# String date comparison C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an application that pulls a date from a MySQL database (string format: 01-jan-2000).  I need to compare this data with the date entered in a TextBox.

This is what i have so far:

```
String query = "select * from tb_demographic_data where date_of_birth LIKE '%" +
       txb_startDate.Text + "' OR (str_to_date(date_of_birth,'%d,%b,%Y') <= 
       str_to_date('"+txb_startDate.Text+"','%d,%b,%Y'))
```

When I run the query I get no results.  Nothing is wrong with my sql code.  I think the error occurs when i change the string to a date with `str_to_date()`. Can anyone help?

Comment: try outputting the mysql date to textbox and check if the formats are same...

Comment: This looks like a SQL injection waiting to happened.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do string comparisons of dates.  Change the column in the database to be a date, and update your query to accept a date value using a parametrized statement or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your date format is wrong... `'%d,%b,%Y'` is saying that the separators are commas. I would imagine you want something like `'%d-%b-%Y'`.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. however now the query just brings up all the fields in the db. it still doesn't recognize the comparison

Comment: In that case perhaps you could post the SQL string just before it is sent to the database. Have you written a SQL statement that you can run directly against the database (ie not via the code) that does what you want? And why is your date in the database a string? :)

Comment: i will test it in mysql alone and try changing the field to DateTime. thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

As Nikhil pointed out, having a user enter a date in a date/calendar/clock control is typically a much better choice.  In addition, I would highly recommend not taking user input from a textbox and simply pasting it inside a SQL string.  This leads to [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

I would recommend that you either use one of the above recommended controls to have users specify a specific `DateTime`, or [convert the data in your text box to a `DateTime` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c).  Assuming you are using `DbCommand` objects to run your query, you can then use a parameterized query and pass in your `DateTime` as a parameter, rather than directly putting it into the command.  Your SQL could look like the following:

```
select * from tb_demographic_data
where date_of_birth <= @startDate
```

You would then have to add a `DbParameter` to your `DbCommand` with a `ParameterName` of `"@startDate"` and a `Value` of your `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. I'm sure its not the most efficient way to do this but I'm fairly new to this. Here it is: I just parsed the two strings as dates and calculated the date difference between them. If the answer is positive then the first date comes before the second and vice versa

```
select * from tb_demographic_data 
where date_of_birth 
    LIKE '%" + txb_startDate.Text + "' 
    OR (datediff(str_to_date('" + txb_startDate.Text + "', 
                             '%d-%b-%Y'), 
                 str_to_date(date_of_birth,
                             '%d-%b-%Y'))>=0)
```

Comment: DO NOT build sql queries by concatenating untrusted (read: user-supplied) strings.  Use a parametrized query and add the user input as parameters.